# Solucion de problema con Queue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, queue

tengo problemas para aplicarle los métodos a esta Queue y resolver lo que me pide...

Implementar la función cobrarClientes, que recibirá una
Queue (fila) de clientes que esperan para realizar el pago
de sus compras del supermercado.

-La función debe evaluar si el primer cliente de la fila poseee dinero suficiente
para abonar los productos que desea comprar. En caso de ser así, debe remover
al cliente de la fila.

-En caso de presentarse un cliente que no posee dinero suficiente, debe dejar de
recibir clientes de evaluar los clientes de la fila, y retornar un array con los NOMBRES de los clientes que fueron correctamente retirados de la fila.

```
//Complementarios//

function Queue() {
  this.array = [];
}

Queue.prototype.enqueue = function (elemento) {
  return this.array.push(elemento);
};

Queue.prototype.dequeue = function () {
  return this.array.shift();
};

Queue.prototype.size = function () {
  return this.array.length;
};

const clientes1 = new Queue();

clientes1.enqueue({
  nombre: 'Jorge',
  dinero: 1500,
  precioProductos: 1000,
});

clientes1.enqueue({
  nombre: 'Mateo',
  dinero: 2000,
  precioProductos: 1900,
});

clientes1.enqueue({
  nombre: 'Mora',
  dinero: 5000,
  precioProductos: 5800,
});

/////////////////////////////////////
//Problema//


function cobrarClientes(clientes) {

var nombres = new Queue;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++){
    if(clientes.array[i].dinero > clientes.array[i].precioProductos){ 
      nombres.enqueue(clientes.array[i].nombre);
      console.log(clientes.array[i].nombre);
      //clientes.dequeue()
    }
  
  }
 return nombres.array

}
 
// A la hora de invocar dequeue(), se me rompe todo, y por ende no puedo //sacar a los primeros de la lista, al no poder quitar elementos que cumplen //con la condición. 
// No llego al final de la fila, comprobar que pasaron todos y retornar el //false cuando esta vacía.






cobrarClientes(clientes1)) //Deberia devolver: "Jorge", "Mateo"
```

Comment: - Cuando termine de evaluar clientes, la función debe retornar un array con los nombres de los clientes que
han abonado correctamente.
- En caso de quedarse sin clientes en la fila, la función debe retornar false.

Comment: NKETO, si por lo menos hubieras hecho el intento de algo, hubiera podido ayudarte, pero es que tienes literalmente el código de la función en blanco esperando que te hagan la tarea. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/539296/edit) y agrega lo que has intentado aunque no funcione, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Acá no se hacen tareas. Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y realiza el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Muchas gracias @JaimeMenéndez, no tenia idea. Es la primera vez que utilizo esta herramienta. Hace dos dias que estoy atareado con esta actividad ahora edito lo que mas o menos trate de hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por mejorar la calidad del sitio editando tu publicación. Tienes mi voto. Hay algo que me causa duda _"En caso de quedarse sin clientes en la fila, la función debe retornar false._". ¿Qué significa eso? ¿Que si me pasan una cola vacía voy a devolver `false` o que si todos los clientes de la cola tienen dinero para comprar voy a devolver `false`? Está algo confuso, por eso no he agregado respuesta, pero checa mi esbozo [acá](https://playcode.io/909423).

Comment: en vez de un for, usa un while, mientras haya clientes en un queue los sacas y los metes en otro, si hay uno que no puede pagar también cancelas el while, de ahi retornas lo q tengas

Comment: Lo solucione agregándole una condición mas que comprobara de que si  el buche termina y no encontró elementos de corte retorne falso. Ya que la Queue solicitaba retornar las personas que pudieron pagar y si todas podian pagar no hacia falta la lista. **Muchas gracias a ambos por la ayuda** Así lo termine dejando (https://playcode.io/909738) linea 71.

Comment: @NKETO la pregunta no se edita con la respuesta. Se coloca la respuesta debajo, en el apartado de respuesta. En un futuro quien vea la pregunta no verá ningún problema porque lo resolviste en la pregunta. El formato del sitio es preguntas y respuestas. Coloca tu respuesta debajo donde dice "Tu respuesta."

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, Muchas gracias me estas ayudando un montón. Perdón por todo los inconvenientes

Comment: No olvides escribir en el título _cuál era el problema_, además de escribir en la respuesta lo que hace tu código. Por último, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Answer (score 1):

Solucion

```
function cobrarClientes(clientes) {
    let nombres = [];

    // En caso de quedarse sin clientes en la fila, la función debe retornar false.
    if(clientes.size() === 0) return false;

    // Mientras haya clientes en la cola
    while (clientes.size() > 0) {
        // Sacar el cliente de la cola
        let cliente = clientes.dequeue();

        // Si el cliente tiene dinero suficiente para comprar los productos
        if (cliente.dinero >= cliente.precioProductos) { 
            // Se coloca en la cola de nombres de los clientes que pueden comprar
            nombres.push(cliente.nombre);
            // Si el tamaño de clientes llega a 0 y no hay personas que no puedan 
            // pagar. Retorno falso. 
            if(clientes.size() === 0) return false;
        } else {
            // Si el cliente no tiene dinero suficiente para comprar los productos
            // Se devuelve a la cola de clientes y se deja de recibir clientes.
            clientes.enqueue(cliente);
            break;
        }
    }

    return nombres;
}
```